# URL create and new in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a new Rails project. After all, I have a question that I cannot find anywhere or answer by myself so I need your help.

When you create a new object (like Person, Book), you need 2 action: `NEW` and `CREATE`.

When I create new, I have link: `localhost:3000/admin/books/new`

And then when I create fails it will return `ERROR MESSAGE` anf this link: `localhost:3000/admin/books/create`

```
If I click in url and `ENTER`. It will wrong.
```

I'm trying to use `redirect_to` or `render` if creation is failed. But nothing happen, sometimes it go to `new` page but it don't show error message.

I think is a rule in Rails. `But I still want to ask that anyone have any idea to resolve this problem??? Go to`new`link with`error message`if they're failed`

More details: I'm using Typus gem to create view for admin. So I can't find Routes file. I run `rake routes` and get:

```
GET /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
POST /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
PATCH /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
DELETE /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
```

And controller when create book:

```
if result
    format.html { redirect_on_success }
    format.json { render json: @item }
else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

Thanks for your helping :)

Comment: Could you show your specific route for those models? I guess you are not using RESTful.

Comment: show us what you have in your routes and controller

Comment: I'm using TYPUS gem for admin create new book. So I can't find routes.

Comment: But when I run `rake routes`, I get the result:


GET /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)


POST /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)


PATCH /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)


DELETE /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)

Answer (score 1):

That is the normal way that Rails works. To understand what is happening, you need to understand what is HTTP verbs and how they works.

When you visit `http://localhost:3000/book/new`, you are making a request to the server to get (GET Verb) some information. In this case, a form to submit a new Book.

When You click submit, you are Sending (POST verb) data to the Server. On Rails, the link `http://localhost:3000/book/create` is available only by POST request. That is why, when you visit this link directly, it says that the route was not found.

This line:

```
# ...
else
    format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity 
end
```

means that, if something wrong happens, it need to render the view of new action again without redirect. This way you are able to find the errors on the object you are trying to save.

If you redirect, you will lose the actual (at the create stage) object. New object without data and error will be created on the `new` action:

```
def new
    @book = Book.new
end
```

For this reason you are unable to access the error mensagens when you redirect. Only you can do on redirection, is setting a flash message:

```
if @book.save
     redirect_to @book
else
     flash[:error] = "An error occurred while saving Book."
     redirect_to :new 
end
```

2 resources that will hep you with that:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: I understood what you explain. But I need a error message from model validation (not controller). And I know it is the way Rails works, but I still want to find a mesure for this case. Anyway, thanks for your helping :)

Comment: I dont know if it the correct solution... but I think, a solution that could work is pass a variable to flash with error messages from the object. like: `flash[:error] = @book.errors`

Comment: In here I use format.html. So it's hard for me to use your solution.

I'm trying with flash and redirect_to  and I get message`You are being redirected.` (Not show page)

And then I'm trying with flash and render  and I get messsage `#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fed37b48c10>` ( show page).

Both of them are still show this link `localhost:3000/admin/books/create` :)

Comment: show me please hou did you change your code to try to use my solution

Comment: `else`   ` flash[:errors] = @item.errors`   `format.html { redirect_to 'new', status: :unprocessable_entity }`  `format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }`   `end` (Sorrry, I don't know how to format in comment!)

Answer (score 1):

On your rake routes, you could notice that it is prefixed with `admin`.

```
GET /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
POST /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
PATCH /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
DELETE /admin/books/(:/action(/:id)) (.:format)
```

Did you try it to prefixed with `admin/books/new`? And `admin/books/create`? Then notice your url: you use only `book` since on your routes it is `books`.

Try:

`http://localhost:3000/admin/books/new`

`http://localhost:3000/admin/books/create`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding about my question because of my carelessness. Sorry about that. (I will edit again).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting that error, there (by default) is no `/create` path, especially with a `GET` verb.

Whilst you *can* create your own `/create` path, your functionality is [conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope :admin do
   resources :books, :people, only: [:new, :create] #-> url.com/admin/books/new
end

#app/controllers/books_controller.rb
class BooksController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json, :html, only: :create #-> needs responders gem
   def new
      @book = Book.new
   end

   def create
      @book = Book.new book_params
      respond_with @book if @book.save
   end
end
```

The above is the standardized (working) way to achieve what you want.

--

As per the [routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions), there is no `/create` path:

```
POST    /photos photos#create   create a new photo
```

Comment: Problem is I'm using Typus. It automatically create routes for me, so I can't handle that. So I just want fix it in controller (just my idea). Do you have any idea, because I can't fix the routes?

Comment: Okay, it would have been helpful to know this, would you rather I delete the answer?